# Saving one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity

Tags: hibernate

I have some POJOS which are as follows:

1. Student.java
2. Feedback.java
3. Forum.java
4. Solution.java
5. Suggestions.java

There is one more class through which i am adding a user to the mysql database using hibernate.
This is the method that does that:

```
            import java.util.List;
            import org.hibernate.Transaction;
            import java.util.Date;
            import java.util.HashSet;
            import java.util.Set;
            public class HibernateExample 
            {
                public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                    addUser();
                }

                private static void addUser() 
                {
                    Student user = new Student();
                    user.setEmailId("harshal@gmail.com");
                    user.setFname("fd");
                    user.setLname("dsfds");
                    user.setStuId(43);

                    Set<Feedback> feeds=new HashSet<Feedback>();
                    Feedback feed=new Feedback();
                    feed.setFeedId(1);
                    feed.setFeedDate(new Date());
                    feed.setStudent(user);
                    Suggestions suggestions=new Suggestions();
                    suggestions.setSugession("imrove hjds");
                    suggestions.setSugessionId(43);
                    suggestions.setFeedbacks(feeds);
                    feed.setSuggestions(suggestions);
                    feeds.add(feed);
                    user.setFeedbacks(feeds);


                    Set<Forum> forums=new HashSet<Forum>();
                    Forum fo=new Forum();
                    fo.setQuestion("what's the dks?");
                    fo.setQuestionDate(new Date());
                    fo.setQuestionId(23);
                    fo.setQuestionTitle("how rto");

                    Solution solution=new Solution();
                    solution.setSolId(4554);
                    solution.setSolution("get taht girl");
                    fo.setStudent(user);
                    forums.add(fo);
                    solution.setForums(forums);
                    fo.setSolution(solution);

                    user.setFeedbacks(feeds);
                    // 2. Create DAO
                    StudentDAO dao = new StudentDAO();

                    // 3. Start the transaction
                    Transaction tx = dao.getSession().beginTransaction();

                    // 4. Add user
                    dao.save(user);

                    // 5. Commit the transaction (write to database)
                    tx.commit();

                    // 6. Close the session (cleanup connections)
                    dao.getSession().close();
                }
            }
```

The error that i am getting  is :

```
            WARN: HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
                Unsaved transient entity: ([Suggestions#43])
                Dependent entities: ([[Feedback#1]])
                Non-nullable association(s): ([Feedback.suggestions])
            Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation: Feedback.suggestions -> Suggestions
                at org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.java:135)
                at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(ActionQueue.java:240)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(SessionImpl.java:709)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:759)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:749)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
                at StudentDAO.save(StudentDAO.java:32)
                at HibernateExample.addUser(HibernateExample.java:144)
                at HibernateExample.main(HibernateExample.java:15)
```

Although the error looks self-explanatory i am having some problems in the sequence
in which i should perform the operations in add user method().
So what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Saving the `Student` causes both the `Feedback` and the `Suggestions` entities to be saved by some order which is unrelated to the fact that `Feedback` is dependent on `Suggestions`.

Try saving the `Suggestions` entity first and only then the `Student` (which will cause the `Feedback` to also be saved, but this time *after* `Suggestions`), like that:

```
dao.save(feed);
dao.save(user);
```

You might encounter additional mal-ordered save operations so you'll just have to save them separately accordingly.

Comment: Still getting the same errors.I moved the suggestions entities at the top of method adduser.

Comment: @user1788048 that's not what I meant. See the code I added to my answer. You should first save `feed` in a separate operation and then save `user` in another.

Comment: dao is a StudentDAO object and when i try to use dao.save(feed) then it tells me that argument is not apllicable. Should i  create an FeedbackDAO object and then use that object to save?

Comment: @user1788048 That would be good for start. Though I'm not sure I understand the implication of the DAO being a `StudentDao` (does it inherit something with generics?). So try it and let's see that it works. Also, please post `StudentDao` so it'll be clear what is what.

Comment: As there are more than 12-15 files, i can't post the entire code.I have uploaded it here.  http://speedy.sh/4GRuf/hibernatetrial.zip

Comment: @user1788048 that URL is blocked here... First just try creating another Dao (`FeedbackDao`) and see if there are no more errors.

Comment: @user1788048 if you could just clarify generically how do your Daos look like instead of posting the 15 classes that might just be enough.

Comment: I was discussing this matter with my colleague and he said that  we don't have to insert the data of another tables while inserting in a particular table.In my case , Mapping of relationship will be required while fetching the contents from multiple tables and not while inserting the content , so that functionality is not required now.I am now simply inserting the data separately in the required tables. Thanks a lot for helping..

Answer (score 1):

**Saving version information to existing entities helped me here.**

It was a different problem for me, but the error was the same.

For ex.

**Entity1** was already saved in the database.

**Entity2** I was trying to save, whereas Entity 1 was linked to Entity 2.

While saving Entity I was getting the same type of error message hence after checking the version information on Entity 1, I found that the version was null hence I set the version to 0 and then tried saving new Entity 2, It worked.